# Why we can't directly calculate the probability that the E is the translation of the F using the statistical translation models

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

Context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_machine_translation

Since we can use the statistical translation models to calculate the probability that the F is the translation of the E, why we can't calculate the probability that the E is the translation of the F using the statistical translation models.

$$\mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_{e}  p(e \mid f) = \mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_{e} p(e)\times p(f \mid e)$$

Comment: Context, please.  What are $E$ and $F$?  What IBM Model?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry. My bad. I have added the context link into question description.